# Echo get_post_meta() in a function

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I didn't find similar questions like mine, so I hope someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong.

I would like to echo from the backend wordpress custom fields via a function. This is what I do:

[image: screenshot backend page]

**Function**

```
function add_meta_data() {
    if ( is_page() ) {
        echo'<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_post_meta( $post_id, 'og_title', true ) . '">';
    }
add_action('wp_head','add_meta_data',1);
```

The above returns in an empty meta data:

[image: frontend page head result]

Before you comment about *"Why not using existing SEO plugins?"*, that is the whole thing I'd like to eliminate plugins which come with too many unused function and try to use existing features from WP.

Comment: where is post_id in get_post_meta?

Answer (score 0):

use this function with post id/

```
get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_meta_key', true );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the og_title through get_post_meta in db then you will definitely have the og_title. But seems you are not passing the post_id which is mandatory.

Please go through the doc mentioned on WP

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

You need to put the post_id to get the meta data. See the code below

```
function add_meta_data() {
    if ( is_page() ) {
        echo'<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_post_meta($post_id ,'og_title' ) . '">';
    }
add_action('wp_head','add_meta_data',1);
```

Comment: if you want to go the extra mile, if custom field `og_title` is not defined use the current page title as fallback instead of leaving the property empty

Comment: Yes you can use the same. Even in most cases, the title is used as og_title. for og description, you can use the excerpt of post.

Comment: @Kevin I understand, but that's the case, I want to inject a different title for the `og` than the existing title for the page. I have tried your proposal, but this results as well in an empty meta tag.

Comment: @Demian

first try to print the output and do check what is the output? print_r(get_post_meta($post_id ,'og_title' ));

Comment: Also do check your wp_postmeta table and check the og_title for the post_id is exist or not? If not then the function will not work.

Comment: @Rohit it is likely that it doesn't exist in `wp_postmeta`. My limitations in php knowledge thought that saving a custom field would do that, so this means I have to inject it into `wp_postmeta` first?

Comment: Youps, you have to first save it to wp_postmeta using add_post_meta function. Only then you can get the og_title.

Comment: @Rohit I understand now, this is where my mistake is and I couldn't find this in WP docs.

Comment: @Rohit I checked postmeta and I see this [screenshot wp_postmeta](https://prnt.sc/rennjq)

Comment: So now try to echo this function - print_r(get_post_meta('9145' ,'og_title' )); where 9145 is your post_id. See what happens?

Comment: You are just missing then post_id. Data is being saved into the DB.

Comment: @Rohit I found the problem `$post_id` is not defined, that's why there is an empty meta tag on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I made in the function is that `$post_id` is not defined, as this is not a global variable. What needs to be done is:

```
function add_meta_data() {
    if ( is_page() ) {
        $post_id = get_the_id();
        echo'<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_post_meta( $post_id, 'og_title', true ) . '">';
    }
add_action('wp_head','add_meta_data',1);
```